# AppDelegate unknown issue that allows to build app but then crashes it, how to fix?

Tags: xcode, swift, appdelegate

I'm really new at coding with Swift language and developing for iOS and OS X languages in general. So I was writing a simple program, just to get to know some basic features, syntax, etc of the language, and then I got this weird problem in the AppDelegate.swift file of my project:

[image]

Then I just tried to make a empty app, and then reinicialize Xcode, but neither of these worked. So I started a blank new project and I just kept having this error. Then I reinstalled Xcode and create new projects, but the same problem hasn`t let me work since then!!

Can anyone help me please? I know it might be ridiculous to fix, but I really don`t know how.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: People, I need help, really, pleaseeee

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem once and I guess it is some kind of bug in Xcode. I just disabled global breakpoints by toggle global breakpoint state(blue arrow like symbol in lower pane) and then press continue execution.

Comment: Tried to do this, but it did`t work... Well... thanks anyway